# Capybara integration view testing not reading the correct data -ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

https://github.com/adamteddychang/The-Budget/tree/view-testing

All the fields are filled out accordingly
User can be created successfully in the rails console with the same parameters
but unable to log in with the same credentials in the testing environment
[The ran test that says invalid login credentials even the credentials are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9KnX.png)

The app is working completely fine, it is just not working in testing

Comment: Since it's telling you the Email or password is incorrect, look at the test.log to see exactly what is being submitted by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using Devise gem. You are visiting the user_session_path, but by Devise default it should be new_user_session_path.

Just change
user_session_path

To:
new_user_session_path

Comment: yes I have done that, it's not the issue of the path because in the terminal it is showing the right path, it is just not logging in even though the password and email are correct

Comment: please try to add this: config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature in your rails_helper.rb (spec folder)

Comment: Hi, it was resolved by adding  `include Warden::Test::Helpers` in the rails_helper.rb file. Thank you for your help!